# Вопрос по ООП non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, ооп

Всем привет, возникает ошибка:

> "Error:(6, 21) java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context".

В данной строчке: `Car myCar = new Car();`

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.start();
        myCar.stop();
        myCar.start();
        myCar.drive(5);
        myCar.stop();
        myCar.drive(5);
    }

    public class Car {
        boolean driveOn;
        int allLong = 0;

        public void start() {
            System.out.println("Мы включили двигатель!");
            driveOn = true;
        }

        public void stop() {
            System.out.println("Мы выключили двигатель");
            driveOn = false;
        }

        public int drive(int howLong) {
            if (driveOn = true) {
                allLong += howLong;
                System.out.println("Мы проехали " + allLong + " километров!");
                return allLong;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Двигатель выключен!");
                return allLong;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Попробовал исправить и получилось только так:

```
public static class Car
```

Кто нибудь может помочь в объяснении данной проблемы? Если ли другие способы решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так работает нестатический внутренний класс в Java. Его объекты имеют смысл только в контексте объекта родительского класса, что отсутствует в статическом методе `main`.

Вынесите класс `Car` из `Main`.